# What's wrong with the PHP syntax here?

Tags: php

I'm having hard time to figure out whats wrong in this code. I tried many variations but still getting error in this line:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content)" .
    "VALUES ('$row['Name']','$row['Email']',$row['title'],$row['content'])";
```

What could be wrong?

here's the rest of the code:

```
<?php


 // connect to the database
 include('config2.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'x', 'x', 'x')
    or die('Error');

    $name = $row['Name'];
    $email = $row['Email'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];


    $result = mysql_query("select *stories WHERE id=$id")
             or die(mysql_error()); 

    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $query= "INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content)" .
    "VALUES ('$row['Name']','$row['Email']',$row['title'],$row['content'])";

   or die('Error querying database.');

  mysqli_close($dbc);

 }

?>
```

Error message: "parse error expecting identifier (t_string) ' or variable (t_variable) ' or number (t_num_string) '"

Comment: It'd be great if you could show the rest of the code around this line... like what is `$row`....?

Comment: not sure, but try to add a space before VALUES

Comment: and whats the error message?

Comment: try this: $query= "INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content) VALUES ('".$row['Name'] ."','".$row['Email']."',$row['title'],$row['content'])";

Comment: try changing the second line to this:
"VALUES ('". $row['Name'] . "','" . $row['Email'] . '," . $row['title'] . "," . $row['content'] . ")";

Comment: You know you're not actually running the query in that code, right?

Comment: Answer below is for the syntax error. You have other larger issues. 1. You are mixing drivers mysqli_ and mysql_. 2. ^ You don't run insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use complex string syntax to properly interpolate those variables. For example:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content)" .
"VALUES ('{$row['Name']}','{$row['Email']}',{$row['title']},{$row['content']})";
```

Though that will only fix one of the issues with the code.

Do note there are plenty of other ways to resolve this one too, such as concatenation instead of interpolation, or string replacements, etc etc.

It might also be worth reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on strings at some point.

Comment: Thanks that solved the parse errors. You're right INSERT is not running I changed it to this `$query= mysql_query("INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content") .
 "VALUES ('{$row['Name']}','{$row['Email']}',{$row['title']},{$row['content']})"` but still not running

Comment: @vyt45 It's probably complaining that because you don't have quotes around the values for title and content which you do for Name and Email.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did that too still getting nothing in the table no sure where could the problem be now.

Comment: Well you could always open a new question if you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "." between your variables and your strings. Like so:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content)" .
    "VALUES (".$row['Name'].','.$row['Email'].','.$row['title'].','.$row['content'].")";
```

However, it looks like you may have some additional issues going on there with the actual SQL query.

Comment: @chris85 Just trying to answer OP's question concerning a PHP error. SQL issues can be addressed in a separate question, if OP wishes to ask.

Comment: Aha, I didn't notice the OP added in there actual error message. Fair enough. Might be worth noting in your answer that there are many other reasons their code won't execute as expected.

Comment: @chris85 Done. :) Good call.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in PHP is to use single quote `'` for strings. Cos PHP looks for variables inside double quoted strings and keeps on sniffing whether there is a variable (or multiple variables) inside the string.

So for example: "A very very long string... $var1 .. long string .. $var2 string" this will run slower compared to 'A very very long string... ' . $var1 . ' .. long string .. ' . $var2 . ' string'; cos when PHP sees single quote it won't sniff for variables inside it thus it's faster.

From my experience, in my early age I worked on a very large php script and used double quotes everywhere. After the above explanation from an expert I converted the whole script to single quote and the performance was much better.

So for your situation I'd suggest and request to use single quotes and it'll avoid confusions as well. Also using `mysql_real_escape_string()` is a good practice to avoid `SQL Injection`.

```
$query= 'INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content) 
VALUES (
\'' . mysql_real_escape_string ($row['Name']) . '\',
\'' . mysql_real_escape_string ($row['Email']) . '\', 
\'' . mysql_real_escape_string ($row['title']) . '\',
\'' . mysql_real_escape_string ($row['content']) . '\')';
```

Comment: Using double vs single quotes (mostly) makes a negligible difference to performance to the point you'd likely not notice it. Especially where connections to other services are involved it's pretty much never going to be a bottleneck.